# Facebook Graph API guarantee specific version at runtime

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I thought I upgraded my app to use version 2.7 of the Graph API, but it appears that there are some version 2.1 calls still occurring.  Is there a test endpoint or way I can modify my test credentials to only accept calls for a specific API version?

I'd like to be able to run my application against this Facebook endpoint/using this Facebook token to ensure that I know what API version all of my calls are using.

Tools like [the Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) help me to craft my requests, but don't validate what my application is using at runtime.

Is there a way for me to modify a production or test application account so that any attempts to call the Facebook API with a version other than 2.7 will throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Use test users.

If you go to Roles -> Test Users in your app dashboard, you can add test users, and then via the Edit button, there is an option "Override the API version in Graph API requests for this test user."

Select that, set Override to Yes, and choose the API version you want to force for all API calls made for this test user.

Then log in as this test user (again, via the Edit button foldout menu), and test your app with it.

Comment: What I want to do is ensure my application is only using v2.7 when making calls.  Changing the test user says it will override calls for that user, but I need to ensure that even without overriding at the user level my app is only making v2.7 calls.  Am I understanding this test user API override properly?

Comment: Well then you will have to go look through your code base, and see if you specified the API version everywhere, and which one. Ideally you should configure this in only one place, and then insert that global value in each place where API requests are made.